# strange error when creating a model with zelig

Tags: r, r-zelig

```
dput(t)
structure(list(Volume = c(2625941L, 4685483L, 3160694L, 2627816L, 
2430273L, 2498011L, 2632445L, 3224434L, 2531941L, 5043867L, 2788003L, 
3278796L, 3273977L, 3192613L, 3456297L, 2668175L, 2805861L, 2689392L, 
2733510L, 3285889L, 2957370L, 3420479L, 3868692L, 4353776L, 3134759L, 
2914727L, 3160491L, 3803716L, 3427911L, 2646258L, 3616962L, 3071943L, 
3013008L, 4024996L, 4357129L, 3110560L, 3063334L, 4537971L, 1902002L, 
2618413L, 2473005L, 2844029L, 2398462L, 3406776L, 3071573L, 3714231L, 
4276458L, 3825187L, 2652650L, 3040994L, 2695117L, 3038566L, 2695652L, 
2919113L, 2840214L, 2768958L, 5246649L, 3023172L, 3565584L, 2928450L, 
3503840L, 2948165L, 3512192L, 3409995L, 3511665L, 3155152L, 3020401L, 
2758133L, 2548245L, 3033309L, 2740213L, 2851881L, 3134557L, 4445879L, 
3173913L, 3720477L, 3753070L, 3609973L, 3826284L, 4864280L, 4159588L, 
3095322L, 3138732L, 3591433L, 3063357L, 3215559L, 3258059L, 3559727L, 
4886550L, 4025763L, 4108614L, 5720774L, 4075195L, 3322352L, 3048940L, 
3249172L, 3148053L, 3321660L, 3159642L, 3976820L, 3848960L, 3466783L, 
3811408L, 6033563L, 4114751L, 3181385L, 2926695L, 2866148L, 2692198L, 
3400891L, 2922295L, 3912049L, 3079066L, 2833293L, 3560196L, 3317644L, 
3151086L, 3776538L, 5479510L, 3954497L, 3594429L, 3088262L, 2778180L, 
3532457L), SLA = c(28L, 44L, 12L, 28L, 4L, 28L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 
8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 32L, 4L, 36L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 20L, 8L, 32L, 
12L, 32L, 8L, 16L, 40L, 8L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 20L, 16L, 4L, 12L, 
8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 28L, 28L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 
8L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 44L, 12L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 24L, 36L, 16L, 
40L, 24L, 4L, 44L, 8L, 16L, 12L, 8L, 32L, 12L, 20L, 16L, 28L, 
8L, 24L, 24L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 44L, 12L, 24L, 40L, 
8L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 16L, 24L, 8L, 36L, 48L, 36L, 12L, 36L, 
28L, 20L, 12L, 20L, 32L, 24L, 4L, 12L, 16L, 8L, 24L, 16L, 36L, 
44L, 12L, 8L, 4L), Duration = c(21L, 25L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 20L, 
17L, 20L, 12L, 15L, 31L, 12L, 24L, 16L, 25L, 13L, 13L, 20L, 21L, 
20L, 26L, 15L, 26L, 21L, 27L, 20L, 34L, 29L, 74L, 62L, 33L, 27L, 
26L, 23L, 30L, 26L, 26L, 18L, 19L, 13L, 25L, 18L, 20L, 18L, 37L, 
20L, 22L, 25L, 24L, 22L, 42L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 28L, 18L, 28L, 32L, 
23L, 31L, 12L, 30L, 40L, 30L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 27L, 21L, 31L, 23L, 
26L, 14L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 21L, 23L, 12L, 22L, 24L, 29L, 
36L, 19L, 21L, 25L, 24L, 29L, 26L, 34L, 33L, 17L, 17L, 24L, 19L, 
18L, 12L, 18L, 11L, 19L, 22L, 48L, 49L, 25L, 16L, 43L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 15L, 38L, 19L, 22L, 28L, 28L, 34L, 16L, 53L, 38L, 23L, 27L, 
17L)), .Names = c("Volume", "SLA", "Duration"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L))
```

when I do this:

```
z.out1 <- zelig(Duration ~ Volume, model = "logit", data = t)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1L, 0L)) : 
  attempt to set rownames on object with no dimensions
```

any ideas?

Comment: Generally logit models have a dichotomous variable on the LHS of the formula. Your Duration column is not.  Notice that the error points to the fact that the code was "expecting" to create a variable with values 0 and 1. (Not the most informative error message I will admit.)

Comment: @DWin, I tried normal, ls models. The same error.

Comment: I do not get the same error with either "ls" or "normal" as model choices. Since I just downloaded Zelig from CRAN minutes ago, I think I have a reasonably current version: 4.0-11 running in R 2.15.1 on a Mac running SnowLeopard.